# learning curve of multiclass classification task

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv, imbalanced-data

I'm trying to do a multiclass classification using multiple machine learning using this function that I have created:

```
def model_roc(X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=11)
    

    pipeline1 = imbpipeline(steps = [['pca' , PCA()],
                                     ['smote', SMOTE('not majority',random_state=11)],
                                     ['scaler', MinMaxScaler()],
                                     ['classifier', LogisticRegression(random_state=11,max_iter=1000)]])

    
    stratified_kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=11)
    
    param_grid1 = {'classifier__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],'classifier__C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}

    grid_search1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline1,
                               param_grid=param_grid1,
                               scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, average='weighted',multi_class='ovo', needs_proba=True),
                               cv=stratified_kfold,
                               n_jobs=-1)
    print("#"*100)
    print(pipeline1['classifier'])
    grid_search1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    cv_score1 = grid_search1.best_score_
    test_score1 = grid_search1.score(X_test, y_test)
    print('cv_score',cv_score1, 'test_score',test_score1)    
    return
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I get multiple metrics from the same function(ROC/Accuracy/precision and F1_score) as it is imbalanced data with multiple classes?
2. I need to plot the learning curve, but I don't know how to do this out of my function.

Comment: I recommend you to stop a bit and take time to read how to make a pipeline and how to use cross validation. You are repiting yourself a lot. Clean that and then come back again.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I edited the publication and the code if you have an answer for the 2nd question thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to plot a learning curve of `roc_auc_score`

```
def plot_learning_curves(model,X,y):
     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=11)
     train_scores ,test_scores = [],[]
     for m in range(1,len(X_train)):
        model.fit(X_train[:m],y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict =model.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
        train_scores.append(roc_auc_score(y_train,y_train_predict))
        test_scores.append(roc_auc_score(y_test,y_test_predict))
     plt.plot(train_scores,"r-+",linewidth=2,label="train")
     plt.plot(test_scores,"b-",linewidth=2,label="test")
```

we iterate m from 1 to the whole length of the training set, slicing m records from the training data and training the model on this subset.

The model's roc_auc_score will be calculated and added to a list, showing the progress of it's roc_auc_score as the model trains on more and more instances.

-modified from ageron-handsonml2